# appwarp chatroom not showing

Tags: android, appwarp

I am using AppWard to adding a chat feature in my android app and i create the app and add a chat room at https://apphq.shephertz.com/service/deployApp?appwarp=true

i also changed the apikey and secretkey at constants.java but my app did't shows the my chat room

package appwarp.example.chatdemo;

```
public class Constants {

public static String apiKey =<apikey>;
public static String secretKey =<secretkey>;

}
```

please could some one help me is there any other part of code i need to change in matchmakingandchatdemo project

Comment: What example are you exactly referring to? Can you provide a link?
Also have you created rooms? You will need to create rooms either through dashboard or through createRoom API

Comment: You might have created keys of App42 app type. Make sure you have selected AppWarp as App type while creating keys.